# The add button defined to make more input values on command, is erasing all the existing values, is there a way to avoid that?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
"use strict"
let count=0;

addbutton=document.getElementById('addBoxes');
form=document.getElementById('inputs');
addbutton.onclick=function(){
    count++;
    form.innerHTML+='<input type="text" name="pid'+count+'"><br><br>'
}
```

```html
<form id='inputs' action="/project_details" method="POST">
    <label>Project ID</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="pid"><br><br>
    <br><button>submit</button><br>
</form>
<button type="button" id="addBoxes">add</button>
```

So the button add allows the code to add more input values using JS, but every time I were to click add, it takes away the existing values.

Example:

input ABCD

press add

now the screen will display 2 empty input boxes

---

Also is there a way I could better station my submit button, cause when I add an input value it shows up beside the submit button, instead of pushing it down.

Comment: Where would you want the existing values to be shown?

Comment: in the same input values, like if I were to put into box 1: ABCD and press add, then box 1= None

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` _ever_ unless you intend to completely replace the contents. In your case, you need `appendChild`

Comment: Or actually, in light of the submit button, `insertBefore`. It will be easier if you get rid of all those `<br>` tags and use CSS instead to align your items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding to the innerHTML of the form, use appendChild:

```js
let count=0;

    addbutton=document.getElementById('addBoxes');
    form=document.getElementById('inputs');
    addbutton.onclick=function(){
        count++;
        let newChild = document.createElement("input")
        newChild.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newChild.setAttribute("name", "pid"+count);
        
        form.appendChild(newChild);
    }
```

```html
<form id='inputs' action="/project_details" method="POST">
    <label>Project ID</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="pid"><br><br>
    <br><button>submit</button><br>
</form>
<button type="button" id="addBoxes">add</button>
```

If you want to append after the input without screwing up the button placement, as you mentioned:

```js
let count=0;

addbutton=document.getElementById('addBoxes');
form=document.getElementById('inputs');
addbutton.onclick=function(){
    let refNode = document.getElementsByName("pid"+count);
    count++;
    let newChild = document.createElement("input")
    newChild.setAttribute("type", "text");
    newChild.setAttribute("name", "pid"+count);
    
    refNode[0].parentNode.insertBefore(newChild, refNode[0].nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<form id='inputs' action="/project_details" method="POST">
        <label>Project ID</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="pid0"><br><br>
        <br><button>submit</button><br>
</form>
<button type="button" id="addBoxes">add</button>
```

Comment: No problem, I added an edit to help you with the button placement issue. I append the element after the previous child instead.